# Can one sign as a witness on a Conservative/ Reform Ketubah?

Tags: halacha, marriage, ketubah, reform-judaism, conservative-judaism

Was at a Conservative friend's house the other day, and noticed the Ketubah from their wedding on their wall. I went to look at it and saw  4 witnesses had signed it: 2 men & 2 women.

If an Orthodox person was asked by a Conservative/ Reform friend to be a witness for [such a Ketubah](https://www.ketubah.com/files/PDF/T-aa.k2.torref.circ.pdf) (or a Ketubah that deviates from accepted halachik practice), would they be allowed to?

Comment: I was asked to do this once, and my rabbi suggested that I not do so. On the other hand, I was also asked another time to be a witness for a wedding that was ostensibly Orthodox, though the bride and groom certainly did not observe at that level (i.e. they were living together before the wedding), and I was advised that I could do so and that it was even a good idea for me to maintain my relationship with the couple so they'd be friends with someone who was practicing at a higher level.

Comment: Is it any worse than signing a secular contract between the two?

Comment: @AlBerko right but re: מראית עין, the person is at the wedding anyways. Perhaps it could be a problem of "validating" this non-halachik practice?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102006/can-a-ketubah-not-mention-monetary-obligations

Answer (score 1):

**הוכח תוכיח את עמיתך**, rebuking a person who is doing a sin.

[Vayikra 19:17] "You shall surely rebuke your fellow, but you shall not bear a sin on his account."

[See Rambam (Sefer Hamitzvos, Assei, 205) "The 205th mitzvah is that we are commanded to admonish a person who is performing a transgression or who is preparing to do so. One must verbally warn him and admonish him..."]

In this case, by being an active participant in a Conservative/Reform ceremony, by serving as a witness on their Ketubah, is the not only the antithesis of rebuke, but also sends the message that we tacitly condone their deviation(s) from accepted Halachic practice.

[Note: This answer draws inspiration from the [Sefer Chafetz Chaim (Essin, 5, Be'er Mayim Chaim)](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14233&st=&pgnum=35&hilite=) who formulates a similar ruling regarding someone who neglects to admonish a person who is beginning to speak Lashon Hara or Rechilus, and is an ample precedent for this Halachic approach].

Comment: This is a good example of why not to Paskin out of a Sefer HaMitzvot or a pasuk. But if we are ruling out of peskuim may as well Paskin like אַל תּוֹכַח לֵץ פֶּן יִשְׂנָאֶךָּ הוֹכַח לְחָכָם וְיֶאֱהָבֶךָּ

Answer (score -2):

This is a draft answer outlining the major considerations:

1. **"מראית עין"** - there's a problem of being perceived in public as "turning sides". Especially valid if the Ketubah mentions explicitly it follows a different tradition, Reform for example.
2. **Signing on what one sees is not a problem**. Even a Reform Ketubah (as a simple, non-religious contract) isn't worse than any secular contract, so if one can sign a secular contract, one can surely sign on this ... paper.
3. **A Ketubah that doesn't mention the Groom's debt to his bride is not a Ketubah**. Therefore by signing such one is transgressing לפני עוור - misleading the couple into believing they have a Ketubah while they don't and it is Rabbinically prohibited to cohabit without one.

Comment: In my experience a Reform or Conservative Ketubah will not mention the fact that it is such; it's the contract clauses that would typically tip you off to the 'denomination' the sofer and couple belong to